# Android 11 Access Android/data and Android/obb using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-11

Does anyone know how to access Android/data and Android/obb folder of Android 11 using flutter?

Just for your information: according to scoped storage policy of android 11 each app can access its own data and obb folder only.
but somehow there is a way other file explorer using
For Ex:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbVn6Lnje2c

Comment: Flutter or others: Those directories are not readable.

Comment: You can read with explicit permission mixplorer uses that but that's native app

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependency to [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) and then use the function `getExternalStorageDirectory()`.
The result will be for example:

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/your_package_name/files`

For accessing the **obb** folder you can replace `/data/` by `/obb/` in the previous result.